# Грамотная речь, речевые ошибки

Tags: стилистика

Допустима ли такая речевая конструкция: У меня подруга работает учителем (Вместо: моя подруга работает учителем)?

Comment: Вот тут ещё обсуждали разницу, но на английском: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/873/possessive-constructions-мой-vs-у-меня

Comment: oleedd, а вот нельзя сказать, что нет разницы. Вот там примеры. Их собака сдохла. У них собака сдохла. Первое -о  собаке. Куда подевалась собака, она же у них была? А второй вариант - скорее под описание состояния, грусти, сожаления: У них собака сдохла.

Comment: Почему твой отец не пришёл на собрание? - Мой отец в командировке. И почему ты не пойдешь с нами гулять? -У меня отец в командировке, а маме нужна моя помощь.

Comment: Разница всегда есть, но не всегда она чётко выражена. "У меня" действительно употребляется при новом факте. Основная разница в следующем: у меня + вот такие обстоятельства. То есть тогда есть влияние на жизнь рассказчика. В других случаях оттенок разговорности. Но не всегда замена корректна: *У них попугай появился.* Да и не факт, что попугай их, может, дали на время присмотреть.

Comment: Наверное, ещё и уместность или неуместность. Так, в разговоре с подругой я скажу: У меня начальник не очень придирается к мелочам. А если я скажу - Мой начальник не очень придирается к мелочам, это будет уже как-то не разговор с подругой, а, скорее,  какой-то более официальный разговор. Как бы смешение стилей.

Comment: Или, например, если у соседа потёк кран, я скажу: Да зайди в третью квартиру к Сергею, ты же его знаешь. У него брат - сантехник. А вот:- Его брат сантехник, как-то слух режет.

Comment: Незвучание тоже можно объяснить, оно ведь не просто так, но нужно анализировать каждый пример. Оно ещё с местом иногда пересекается: *у меня [на работе] начальник*. С предлогом "у" предложение выступает обстоятельством: *у него (что? какие обстоятельства?) брат - сантехник*. То есть не подчёркивается, что брат именно его. Но это подразумевается по смыслу.

Comment: Предложение строится по аналогии с: *У меня вот такие дела. А у меня вот так-то.* И действительно, слово "вот" можно подставить. А смысл может быть самым разным: *У него колесо лопнуло (совсем не факт, что машина его). У неё деньги заканчиваются. У меня сосед съехал.*

Comment: Да, спасибо, разобрались. В устной речи это не может быть ошибкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выражение и с другими местоимениями используется: *у нас, у них, у него*.
И совсем не обязательно это замена слова "мой":
*У меня охранник уволился.* || "Мой охранник" не совсем корректно, если охранялось предприятие рассказчика.

Разница между "у меня подруга" и "моя подруга":
В первом варианте делается акцент на том, что человек является свидетелем данного факта и твёрдо в нём уверен. Часто подчёркивается отражение на жизни самого рассказчика:
*У меня подруга заболела. Нужно навестить её.* || Замена на "моя" хуже звучит.
То есть что-то происходит у человека — в его жизни.

В некоторых случаях "у меня" даже звучит литературно и выигрывает у "моя", в частности когда изложенный факт влияет на жизнь рассказчика.

Выражение "у меня подруга" даже в книгах встречается. И даже в Нацкорпусе полно примеров. Так что можно даже к литературным зачислять:
[http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&startyear=1984&text=lexform&req=у%20меня%20подруга&endyear=2004&mode=main](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&startyear=1984&text=lexform&req=%D1%83%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0&endyear=2004&mode=main)

Comment: oleedd, Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что вполне допустима: это разговорное сокращение от "У меня есть одна подруга, которая работает учителем." При сокращении сохраняется смысл "*одна* из подруг". Второй вариант соответствует случаю, когда подруга всего одна.

Comment: Но и возникает двузначность: *У меня подруга работает учителем [на дому].*

Comment: oleedd, меня интересовало, можно ли сказать "у меня подруга", вместо "моя подруга".

Comment: Имею в виду, что "у меня" может восприниматься как "у меня дома".

Comment: А, понятно. Но сама конструкция интересует - У меня отец перенёс инфаркт в прошлом году. У меня подруга похудела на 5 кг. У меня мама в прошлом году ездила в Египет.

Comment: Да люди очень часто так говорят — главный показатель допустимости. Но вряд ли такое выражение можно считать литературным (из-за двусмысленности в том числе).

Comment: У меня отец в прошлом году переболел пневмонией. Какая тут двусмысленность? У меня брат бросил пить после того, как чуть не умер.

Comment: Вполне: *У меня брат бросил пить, а когда жил у себя, то не мог бросить самостоятельно.*

Comment: Нет, это уже искусственно. У меня младшая  сестра удачно вышла замуж, а старшая очень несчастна.

Comment: Я о том, что фразы, которые сами по себе могут вызывать двусмысленность, литературными (очень удачными) не являются.

Comment: Согласна. Но в устной речи они же не являются ошибкой? Они приемлемы, ибо в устной речи такие фразы понятны участникам диалога.

Comment: Абсолютно, ввиду большой распространённости.

Comment: Это я и хотела услышать. Потому что мне указали на ошибку, сказав, что это корявая фраза и её употреблять нельзя.

Comment: Появились интересные мысли, лучше оформлю отдельным ответом.

Comment: Забыли про ответ... и фразу «когда подруга всего одна». Это суждение и не убеждает, и странным образом противопоставляет разговорный вариант литературному по количественному признаку.

Comment: shampar,  oleedd, всё-таки "моя подруга работает..." - это когда оба участника диалога понимают, о ком идёт речь, о конкретной подруге. "Помнишь девушку, с которой ты нас знакомила в прошлый раз? Чем она занимается?" -"Моя подруга работает учителем". Вот здесь конкретно, здесь нельзя сказать "У меня подруга работает учителем